# Nginx if $arg rule 404ing requests, why?

Tags: nginx

I have written the following rule in a nginx server block:

```
location /s/sport(/)$ {
  if ($args ~ country){
    rewrite ^(.*) /s/sport/country/$arg_country? break;
  }
}
```

The goal here is to transform legacy URLs such as `http://example.com/rankings/soccer?country=de` to `http://example.com/rankings/soccer/country/de`. This could of course be implemented in the app itself, but we need to do it before hitting the app for performance reasons; these URLs break our caching strategy.

The trouble is when this rule is applied, the following URL formats start to 404:

```
/s/sport
/s/sport?country={iso_code}
/s/sport/country/{iso_code}
```

nginx reports that the request `failed (2: No such file or directory)` which leads me to believe that it is now looking for a physical file with that name instead of passing the path to the app.

How do I fix the rule?

**EDIT:** Here's the full server config I'm trying to add on to:

```
server {
  listen         *:80;
  server_name   example.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  access_log    /path/to/app/logs/access.log        main;
  error_log     /path/to/app/logs/error.log         error;
  root          /path/to/app/current/public;

  location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jp?g|png|swf)(\?[0-9]+)?$ { 
    expires max;
    break;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }

  error_page 503 @maintenance;
  location @maintenance {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about the rest of the configuration? where's the proxy pass or redirect to your "app"?

Comment: @danielgpm Just added in in the question, it's a rails 3 app running on passenger+nginx. I didn't think it was relevant, but there you go.